# How to call a bat file in new window

Tags: winapi, batch-file, cmd

I have a little bat file which calls other bat files:

```
cd C:\Users\Ofis\heroku\1134 && call up.bat
cd C:\Users\Ofis\heroku\5095 && call up.bat
cd C:\Users\Ofis\heroku\9469 && call up.bat
```

It works good, but I want it call .bat files in new windows so it will be synchronous and faster.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of `start` :D

```
cd C:\Users\Ofis\heroku\1134 && start up.bat
cd C:\Users\Ofis\heroku\5095 && start up.bat
cd C:\Users\Ofis\heroku\9469 && start up.bat
```